# Effect of incorrect volume reading on calculated density value

Tags: physical-chemistry, density

> When measuring the density using the displacement method, a student read the initial volume of the water too high, but the final volume reading was correct.
>   This error would cause the calculated density to be too high or too low?  Explain why.

Wouldn't it be too low because the initial volume is too high?

Answer (score 2):

It's asking for the calculated density, not the calculated volume. If the volume, as measured by the student, is too small, then the density (= mass / volume) will be too large. Of course, that's assuming that the mass was measured correctly.